# Are there any philosophies other than Dvaita that have the concept of Nitya Samsari?

Tags: philosophy, vaishnavism, rebirth, dvaita, samsara

I have heard that the Dvaita school of Madhvacharya has the concept of 'Nitya - Samsarins'; which means that as per them a particular class of souls would perpetually be bound in the cycle of rebirth.

Do any other philosophies or schools believe in a similar concept? If yes, which acharyas of their respective school  have mentioned it?